# Xubuntu installation on Virtual Box stuck at splash screen

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu

I am trying to install Xubuntu on Virtual Box, but it always gets stuck at following screen.
I followed instructions from several websites and youtube videos and still the result is same.

I am using a laptop,

- Processor : AMD Ryzen 5 3500U
- RAM : 16 GB
- O/S : Windows 10 home Version 21H1 build 19043.1083, 64bit

For the virtual box,

- Virtual hard disk of 10GB
- RAM : 2048 MB

edit: I tried pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to see what's going on behind but no terminal show up.

[image: screenshot xubuntu installation stuck at check finished:no errors found]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu doesn't boot (stuck on splash)](https://superuser.com/questions/559803/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-stuck-on-splash)

Comment: @HektorGaming Nope. Pressing esc key does nothing. It usually works on bare metal, but not this time.

Comment: Close everything down, start in BIOS and ensure Hardware Virtualization and VT-d have been enabled. Restart and try installing Ubuntu again.